# Write to Google Sheets in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire, google-sheets-api

I'm really confused how to write to an excel sheet, that is public. So far I have downloaded *Alamofire* and *GoogleAPIClientForREST* cocoapods. So I was wondering, if I want to write to the sheet do I first need to implement a google sign in or can I just send data over using *Alamofire*. I am super lost so If someone can help me that would be great.

Google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zJR0uk6Pb6BuxJihFyxwe4ipQdBY4E9FFR74geBj8p0/edit#gid=0

```
func makeAndSendRequest() {
    let baseUrl = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets"
    let spreadsheetId = "1zJR0uk6Pb6BuxJihFyxwe4ipQdBY4E9FFR74geBj8p0"
    let params = ["valueInputOption": "RAW"]
    let range = "Studen!A3:B3"
    //need to add params
    let url = baseUrl + "/" + spreadsheetId + "/values/" + range + "/valueInputOption=RAW/"

    let fullUrl = URL(string: url)!

    //my values
    let requestParams = [
        "values": [
            1,
            2
        ]
    ]


    //my auth is after Bearer so "Bearer 901390"
    let header = ["Authorization":"Bearer "]
    let requestURL = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/\(spreadsheetId)/values/\(range)?valueInputOption=RAW"
    let req = Alamofire.request(requestURL, method: .put, parameters: requestParams, encoding: JSONEncoding.default,headers: header)
    req.responseJSON { response in debugPrint(response) }

}
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Does it require you to sign in? I would think that you would want your spreadsheet to be protected.

Comment: for now I want the simplest way to write to a sheet, so I honestly am not worried about the security aspect, Im mainly looking for a stepping stone because right now im completly lost. Once I understand the basics I will improve upon it and make it log in/protected.

Comment: Cool. Did you try running your code? What happens?

Comment: I get an Alamofire.AFError, so im assuming im not giving the server the proper parameters its asking for.

Comment: What is the error? (`error.localizedDescription`)

Comment: the entire error is :                                                                                        
[Data]: 1663 bytes
[Result]: FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))

Answer (score 1):

Try to fix this first.

`valueInputOption` is a query parameter, see: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update

You URL should at least be:

`let url = baseUrl + "/" + spreadsheetId + "/values/" + range + "?valueInputOption=RAW"`

next you need to fix your request body, range is required per document here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update

`{
  "range": "A3:B3",
  "values": [
    [
      1,
      2
    ]
  ]
}`

This range should be same as your range in your query parameter, say `Sheet1!:A3:B3` as in your query parameter.

Note that it starts with the sheet name, it should not be "studen"

I have used the playground tool on the same page and able to call the api to change the data in your spreadsheet.

At the end I am getting 200 response code and following json:

`{
  "spreadsheetId": "1zJR0uk6Pb6BuxJihFyxwe4ipQdBY4E9FFR74geBj8p0",
  "updatedRange": "Sheet1!A3:B3",
  "updatedRows": 1,
  "updatedColumns": 2,
  "updatedCells": 2
}`

----- Edit -----
As you asked, the API needs Oauth token, the framework to handle this is actually called `G Suite`

Please find the guide here:
https://developers.google.com/gsuite/guides/ios

Comment: hey, I have a quick question soo i tryed and im getting an error telling me I need a auth how do I get this auth key? [Result]: SUCCESS: {
    error =     {
        code = 401;
        message = "Request had invalid authentication credentials.

Comment: @barooongara you are right, you have to be authenticated before you are able to hit the API, the official page has the guide to register it for javascript with api key and clientId. There should be something similar for iOS. See the bottom of https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update the initClient function

Comment: I have obtained this key and put it in my  let header = ["Authorization":"Bearer 18091209 in this format but I still get the same error. I also made sure that the thype is IOS and name:OAuth client. I have updated my post to reflect my current code also.

Comment: can u share how u did the auth part? did u have to update ur pList with root and put the clientID? or how did u use this auth in ur code. Thx for help.